# What is the optimal number of solar panels for my house?

Tags: energy-efficiency, solar-panels

Just had a solar power tech stop by.  With the orientation of our house and the solar load, our property (house + workshop) can support roughly 41 panels.  Each panel provides 370 W (max)...which yields 22.1 MWH per year (assuming 4 hours of sunlight per day).  This is 95% of our annual usage, so I'd expect our bill to drop by 95%.

The quote was $72,000 with monthly payments of $230, which is less than what we pay on budget billing right now.  The overall cost seems high, and I wonder if we should target a smaller fraction.  As an example, if we reduced the panel count to 33 the overall cost drops to $58,000 with payments of $185/month...and this provides ~75% of our annual electric use.

It seems like there is no cost savings here.  For example:

With the 41-panel setup (95% reduction):

- monthly electric bill drops from $250 to $12.50
- monthly payment for panels is $230
- net electric payment is $242.50

With the 33-panel setup (75% reduction):

- monthly electric bill drops from $250 to 62.50
- monthly payment for panels is $185
- net electric payment is $247.50

It seems like, on average, we'll save a few bucks per month.  Is there something wrong in my estimations?  At this point it seems like solar power is **still** unrealistic.

Second question: Is there another way to optimize how many panels we need for our house?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130581/discussion-on-question-by-tnknepp-what-is-the-optimal-number-of-solar-panels-for).